# p:fileUpload NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, file-upload, glassfish, primefaces, nullpointerexception

I am pretty new at developing in JSF and I am busy building a project that requires file uploads but every time I run the uploader I get a java.lang.NullPointerException could anyone please help me with this problem, I have searched the internet extensively and cannot find a solution that works.

I am using NetBeans 7.1.1 and GlassFish to deploy.

My code is as follows:

I have added the following jars to my library:
primefaces-3.2.jar
commons-io-2.3.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar

This is my XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
  <link href="${request.contextPath}/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <title>Tutor Management System</title>

</h:head>
<h:body>

         <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  

    <p:messages showDetail="true"/>  

    <p:fileUpload value="#{myBean.file}" mode="simple" />  

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"  
                actionListener="#{myBean.upload}"/>  

</h:form>  

</h:body>
</html>
```

This is my Backing Bean

```
package BackingBean;

/**
 *
 * @author chrissalerno24
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
public class MyBean implements java.io.Serializable {  

    private UploadedFile file; 
    private static final String MBN = "usernameApplication";
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();


    public UploadedFile getFile() {  
        return file;  
    }  

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {  
        this.file = file;  
    }  

    public void upload() {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>



    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.jsf</location>
    </error-page>

    <context-param>  
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
    <param-value>aristo</param-value>  
</context-param>  

</web-app>
```

I am using PrimeFaces 3.2, JSF 2.0 and GlassFish 3.1.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Received 'java.lang.NullPointerException' when invoking action listener '#{myBean.upload}' for component 'j_idt9'
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BackingBean.MyBean.upload(MyBean.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

SEVERE: JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=j_idt6:j_idt9, Message=java.lang.NullPointerException
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:182)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BackingBean.MyBean.upload(MyBean.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
    ... 33 more
```

The exact line where the uploadFile is breaking is as follows:

```
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
```

This is my faces-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->

<faces-config version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>StudentBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>BackingBean.TutorBackingBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>LoginBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>BackingBean.LoginBackingBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>LecturerBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>BackingBean.LecturerBackingBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>ApplicationBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>BackingBean.ApplicationBackingBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>myBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>BackingBean.MyBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>AdminBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>BackingBean.AdminBackingBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

</faces-config>
```

chrissalerno24

Comment: Can you post the StackTrace and post the exact line where the exception is thrown? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your managed bean does not have any scope. This way JSF defaults to `@NoneScoped`. So a new one is created on every single `#{myBean}` evaluation in EL. Right now there are effectively two created when you select a file and submit the button. The file is set on the first one and the action method is invoked on the second one (which doesn't have the file at all).

You need to put it in a bit wider scope, e.g. the request scope.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {
    // ...
}
```

---

By the way, you've there a dangling `import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;`. This is specific to CDI and would work only when you're managing beans by CDI `@Named` instead of by JSF `@ManagedBean`. Make sure that you use the right package for the bean scope. There's namely also a `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` for the case you need a session scoped JSF managed bean.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I have removed the import statement, forgot to remove it before I posted.  I have implemented your suggestion of @RequestScoped, however I am still getting a NullPointerException.  Could you offer any other advice?

Comment: Are you sure that you imported `@RequestScoped` from the right package? There's another one in `javax.enterprise.context` which you should thus not use when using JSF `@ManagedBean`. Further, have you redeployed the webapp and restarted the server after the change? The annotations are initialized on webapp's startup and can't be hotdeployed. Also, are you sure that there aren't any errors/warnings on webapp's startup?

Comment: I have declared it as session scoped inside the faces-config.xml file.  Will that help?

Comment: The old JSF 1.x `faces-config.xml` way of configuring beans will override the new JSF 2.x way of configuring beans by `@ManagedBean` annotation. The session scope is the wrong scope for forms, but it should work. Back to your concrete problem, try explicitly registering the `FacesServlet` in your `web.xml`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC that seems to have done something, now when I submit a file it says the file is uploaded and there is no error in the stack, however I do not know where the file is uploaded to.  I have added the following code to web-xml for the upload directory, however I cannot locate the file once it has been uploaded.

Comment: Here is code I have added to the web.xml file

`<filter>
       <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
           <param-value>C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\System\Upload\</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
           <param-value>1000000</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </filter>`

Comment: You're welcome. As to your new question, press `Ask Question` button :)